# Loading Image url with PHP from an XML file

Tags: php, html, xml, image, echo

I have an image url stored inside my XML file that I am trying to echo out as a full image on a webpage. In the PHP code below you can see two different ways I am trying to do it through pure HTML outside of the PHP block and another way to do it inside the PHP block with an echo. I would like to correct both ways please, thank you in advanced for the help!

method inside the PHP  gives me an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a3938317/public_html/content.php on line 15


<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("content.xml");

echo $xml->GodOfWar->name;
echo $xml->GodOfWar->info;
echo $xml->GodOfWar->rating;
echo $xml->GodOfWar->img;
echo '<img src=" '$xml->GodOfWar->img;' "/>'; //line 15

?>

<body>

<img src="<?php $xml->GodOfWar->img;  ?>" />

</body>
```

Comment: ...please focus on the line trying to echo an image as i mentioned above. the variable $xml is pulling a url from the tag <img> thats stored inside an xml file. Why is that so hard to understand?

Comment: You hadn't posted anything about getting an error initially.

Comment: The problem is what the error says.

Comment: Also, your lower attempt won't work because you're not outputting anything. If you want to inline echo something, use the syntax `<?=($variableToOutput)?>`, or `<?php echo $variableToOutput; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your line 15 you have:

```
echo '<img src=" '$xml->GodOfWar->img;' "/>'; //line 15
```

That's invalid PHP.  You need to use the `.` operator to concatenate the strings (and remove some unnecessary space inside the `'` and add some outside):

```
echo '<img src="' . $xml->GodOfWar->img . '"/>'; //line 15
```